# Find string value and update a pre-defined value into another field sql query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm a newbie to Access 2010 sql query and need help on the finding a value in the string, if found add the value to another field.

I have a field called Object Name has values like '1110 Ind Lbr - Training', '8510  - Admin/Meeting', 'Ind Lbr-Equip Cal/Maint' we have to find keywords which are part of the string respectively like "Training", " Admin/Meeting" , "Equip cal/Maint" and the resultant output update the keywords into another field called Description which initially will be blank column. Both the fields are in the same table

Comment: Are you familiar with the [LIKE operator](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/like-operator-HA001231490.aspx) in Access SQL?

Comment: HangUp: No there is no only one possible match of a specific keyword in th [Object Name]. Ex.[Object Name] will contain '1110 Ind Lbr - Training' and or '1110 Ind Lbr - Admin/Meeting' and never '1110 Ind Lbr - Training - Amdin/Meeting'. If the keyword "Training' or 'Admin/Meeting', 'Equip Cal/Maint' is found anywhere in the [Object Name] then the respective keyword itself shoyls go into [Description]. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Executed the Select statement

*SELECT m.[object name],k.keywords
FROM tbMain AS m
INNER JOIN tbKeywords AS k
ON m.[object name] ALike '%' & k.Keywords & '%';*

### [Object Name]                      [Keywords]

1110 Ind Lbr - Training            Training
1110 INd Lbr - WCE                 WCE
8510 MFG Indirect- SAFETY          Direct

For 8510 MFG Indirect Lbr - SAFETY I'm supposed to get the keyword as Safety but I get is as Direct.

This is a massive help with the solution given. Thanks